# Virtual touchscreen device did not report support for X or Y axis?

Tags: android, input, touch, linux-device-driver

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to create a virtual touchscreen using uinput in a rooted Android phone.

Even though i am able to create the device,

```
   New device: id=88, fd=170, path='/dev/input/event6', name='uinput-eve', 
   classes=0x4, configuration='', keyLayout='', keyCharacterMap='', 
   builtinKeyboard=false, usingSuspendBlockIoctl=true, usingClockIoctl=false

   Touch device 'uinput-eve' did not report support for X or Y axis!  
   The device will be inoperable.

   Device added: id=88, name='uinput-eve', sources=0x00002002
```

I am not able to create it properly since the device becomes inoperable. Was hopping anyone could shed some light.

This is one of my many attemps that always lead up to that message.

```
struct uinput_user_dev uidev;
struct input_event ev;
int dx, dy;

int fd;
fd = open("/dev/uinput", O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
if (fd < 0) {
    die("error: open");
}

memset(&uidev, 0, sizeof(uidev));
snprintf(uidev.name, UINPUT_MAX_NAME_SIZE, "uinput-eve");
uidev.id.bustype = BUS_VIRTUAL;
uidev.id.vendor = 0x1;
uidev.id.product = 0x1;
uidev.id.version = 1;

if (write(fd, &uidev, sizeof(uidev)) < 0) {
    die("error: write");
}
 /* touch screen event */
    ioctl(fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_ABS);
    ioctl(fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, ABS_X);
    ioctl(fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, ABS_Y);
    ioctl(fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_KEY);
   ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_TOUCH);


if (ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_CREATE,0) < 0) {
    die("error: ioctl");
}
```

Edit1:
 Dug a little deeper and the problem is that aparently mRawPointerAxes are not set, anyone 
has any idea how to set them? The code that follows is from services/input/InputReader.cpp.

```
// Ensure we have valid X and Y axes.
if (!mRawPointerAxes.x.valid || !mRawPointerAxes.y.valid) {
    LOGW(INDENT "Touch device '%s' did not report support for X or Y axis!  "
            "The device will be inoperable.", getDeviceName().string());
    mDeviceMode = DEVICE_MODE_DISABLED;
    return;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: It looks like the x/y axis are established from a device resource.  It looks like it from looking through some touchscreen driver code here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/touchscreen/?a=arm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For absolute axes, you need to define their range in the structure uinput_user_dev. Android will reject an axis as not "valid" if absmin and absmax are equal. (cf. EventHub.cpp  EventHub::getAbsoluteAxisInfo)

Since you didn't define absmax nor absmin, they're both 0. Try adding :

```
uidev.absmax[ABS_X] = 1024; 
uidev.absmax[ABS_Y] = 1024;
```

Change 1024 to the actual resolution you want.

Comment: Thank you that worked, i have a different problem now. I can't seem to inject events into this virtual device. I inject touches as i would on the real touchscreen and it simply doesn't replicate the touch. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to end a sequence with SYN_REPORT, otherwise nothing is processed. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/multi-touch-protocol.txt for more details.